# Supabase returning "JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows returned" in production (vercel)

Tags: next.js, vercel, supabase

I am using a tech stack consisting of Next.js 13 and Supabase. In local development, I can fetch the data properly; however, in production, the same query returns empty data or the error message "JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows returned." I have double-checked environment variables and configurations, and there is nothing wrong there.

I fetch data from Supabase using Next.js's API and then use those endpoints within my frontend to hide/process sensitive data.

I've already tried integrating Vercel and Supabase, using the same variables that these services provided. I believe I have proper Row-Level Security (RLS) policies in place, as they work as intended in local development.

[image: Table RLS Policy Example]
*All the tables have similar RLS policy.*

As per the RLS Policy:

- All **SELECT** queries have `anon` and `authenticated` rules, which, according to the documentation, should be sufficient for reading data without the need for authentication.
- All other types of requests are reserved for the `authenticated` role.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried disabling RLS entirely from all the tables, yet the issue persists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are facing suggests that you are using `.single()` in your query, yet the query returns multiple or no rows. When you use `.single()` on your query, you have to make sure the query returns 1 and only 1 row. Using filters and / or limits.

Comment: I'm fetching an array of records, so unfortunately, that's not the case.

Comment: @AzizKaukawala Can you share the query that is returning this error?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. Issue was entirely something else. Thanks for the help.